# Can I use jQuery ":before" in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to use `:before` to add content before an element. It works fine in Firefox 4, but in IE 7 the content is not displayed.

Can I use jQuery to make the content appear before an element?

Comment: Maybe try using .before() or insertBefore() but we won't know until you post some code

Comment: can't find why it shouldn't work in IE7, so maybe you want to include your code here.

Comment: @melaous `::before` isn't available in IE7 and he is asking whether the effect can be replicated with jQuery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### jQuery equivalent(ish)

Contrary to popular belief (based on comments and other answers), that `.before()` would be the equivalent to `::before` pseudo element **it's not**.

#### The actual approximation would be `.prepend()` function.

Pseudo elements per W3C specification **always render inside container** and never outside. `.before()` actually adds an element outside the element (just before it). That's why using jQuery actually means you have to use a function that inserts inside a container:

```
$("some_container").prepend("<div>::before pseudo element wanna be</div>");
```